# Parent product category page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible in Woocommerce, if the product category page shows its subcategories, to do any actions? I need to add a class to the body tag on such pages. Is it real? Example:

```
function my_custom_body_class_woo_cat($classes) {
    if ( is_product_category() && is_subcategory_show() ) {
        $classes[] = 'my-class';
        return $classes;
    }
}
add_filter('body_class','my_custom_body_class_woo_cat');`
```

I tried to look for solutions, but I didn't find one

Comment: What do you mean it shows it's subcategories? you mean the products that belongs to the subcategories of the parent one
?

Answer (score 1):

I checked [woocommerce conditional tags](https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) and `is_subcategory_show()` is not a valid woocommerce function.

So in order for this to work we need to do our own checks before assigning the extra class or classes to the body.

Here is a code snippet that does what you asked( if i understood your question correctly ):

```php
add_filter('body_class', function ($classList) {
    // Not a product category, return the classList intact
    if (!is_product_category()) {
        return $classList;
    }

    $desiredDisplayType = 'subcategories';
    $term = get_queried_object();

    // Not a parent category, return classList intact
    if ($term->parent !== 0) {
        return $classList;
    }

    // Get the woocommerce category archive display option (the one you set up in the customizer)
    $categoryArchiveDisplayOption = get_option('woocommerce_category_archive_display');

    // Get the display type for the current category
    $currentCategoryDisplayOption = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'display_type', true);

    // The current category displatype isn't the desired one, return classList intact
    if ($currentCategoryDisplayOption !== $desiredDisplayType) {
        return $classList;
    }

    // Neither of the option are the desired one, return classList intact
    if (
        $currentCategoryDisplayOption !== $desiredDisplayType
        && $categoryArchiveDisplayOption !== $desiredDisplayType
    ) {
        return $classList;
    }

    // All checks passed, add my class to body
    return array_merge($classList, ['my-class']);
});
```

Woocommerce has a general option in the customizer where you set up if you want category archives to display subcategories.

Then when you edit a specific category you can assign a display type specific to that category, so this should take precedence over the general option.